# Show Solr Autosuggest results with types/categories

Tags: search, solr, lucene, autosuggest

we are configuring solr for an e-commerce site which features a range of products across multiple categories and brands. In addition to that there is also a number of landing pages which can be reached through the search. So overall, we have 4 types of possible results, I'll use an electronics site as an example:

- Categories (i.e. "Smartphones")
- Brands (i.e. "Samsung"
- Products (i.e. "Samsung Galaxy S4")
- Pages (i.e. "How-To Guide to your Samsung")

What we would like solr to do is

a) show those things in autosuggest (right now it shows the first three, but doesn't show pages as they aren't part of the product catalog through which it searches)

b) show the "type" of the result in the box next to the result. To illustrate, if I would type "Sam", the autosuggest box would look something like this:

```
Samsung                           Brand
Samsung Galaxy S4                 Product
Samsung Galaxy S5                 Product
How-To Guide to your Samsung      Page
Android Smartphones               Category
```

Particularly the last point is really important and we couldn't find any way to do this yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate core for all the stuff you want to be able to auto complete on, where you keep both the type and the value. That way you get the flexibility of adding new auto complete features later, and you'll avoid introducing a wide set of different documents in your main core.

Another option is to add a `type` field to your main schema, and create documents for `Page` objects as well (depending on how you create the existing auto complete categories - if you have three different types of documents in the index already, it would be quick to add a new field that just contains the type of the document as well).